# How do I create an import .lib that would contain the __imp__ symbols?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dllimport

We have an external DLL that we don't have an import lib for, and we have header files that declare functions from that DLL.

Some of those functions are declared with `__declspec(dllimport)`, others aren't. If the attribute weren't used, we could simply create the import library by writing a .def file and running the `lib` tool. However, functions that are declared with the attribute [require special symbols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa271769%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), e.g. function `foo` would require `__imp__foo`.

Is there a simple way to create an import .lib that would contain the `__imp__` symbols, preferably without writing a stub function for each export and generating a fake DLL?

Comment: You'll need to edit the .h file and get rid of the __declspec(dllimport) attribute on the declarations.  Having access to the .h file but not the .lib file is very unusual, contact the owner of the code to obtain the .lib you need.

Comment: @HansPassant, yes, that's what I don't want to do as the headers are supplied to us by the third party. (Yes, we get .lib as well, but it is stripped of some undocumented symbols that we want to use, so we have our own headers which declare these additional functions and need a new .lib).

Comment: ... actually, it's more complicated than that. I don't want to get into unnecessary details, I am convinced that the only way to deal with this is to make the .lib.

Comment: The only other way is to create a dummy DLL project with the same name that exports the exact same functions (code doesn't matter) and build it to create the .lib you need.